# Double lines chart, generate by user

Tags: javascript, css, html, charts

I want a double line chart with a fill between both like this: [image: chart]

But the two lines will be generated by user (He will select by tap or click on the chart). I'm working on HTML/Javascript/CSS.

What are the chart libraries (free) that you recommend to me?

Comment: “Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.” [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

There is a growing number of Open Source and commercial solutions for pure JavaScript charting that do not require Flash. In this response I will only present Open Source options.

There are 2 main classes of JavaScript solutions for graphics that do not require Flash:

```
Canvas-based, rendered in IE using ExplorerCanvas that in turns relies on VML
SVG on standard-based browsers, rendered as VML in IE
```

There are pros and cons of both approaches but for a charting library I would recommend the later because it is well integrated with DOM, allowing to manipulate charts elements with the DOM, and most importantly setting DOM events. By contrast Canvas charting libraries must reinvent the DOM wheel to manage events. So unless you intend to build static graphs with no event handling, SVG/VML solutions should be better.

For SVG/VML solutions there are many options, including:

```
Dojox Charting, good if you use the Dojo toolkit already
Raphael-based solutions
```

Raphael is a very active, well maintained, and mature, open-source graphic library with very good cross-browser support including IE 6 to 8, Firefox, Opera, Safari, Chrome, and Konqueror. Raphael does not depend on any JavaScript framework and therefore can be used with Prototype, jQuery, Dojo, Mootools, etc...

There are a number of charting libraries based on Raphael, including (but not limited to):

```
gRaphael, an extension of the Raphael graphic library
Ico, with an intuitive API based on a single function call to create complex charts
```

**Try this also:**

http://www.highcharts.com !

Creds Jean

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great answer, I think I will start with Raphael but some graphic like http://raphaeljs.com/ichart.html doesn't works on Firefox or Chrome but it works with Internet Explorer. It's normal?

Comment: I noticed it has some compatibility issues with IE but works here thou.

Comment: I tried on another computer and it works well... I don't know what's happend with my computer. Thanks again for your answer :)

Comment: Thats great to hear, goodluck.